# How to change the output of the program so that ALL input can be made first, then give all output

Tags: java, arrays, input, output

When I run my program right now, the output comes directly after each input. So if I input that I want to type in 3 shapes, it'll ask for input for the first shape, and then give the output for that individual shape immediately, and then ask for the input for the second shape and so on.

I would LIKE for it to ask for all input for all shapes/parameters first, and then give all output separately. Is it just a placement problem of the if statement? For whatever reason I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestShapes {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of shapes: ");
    int num = scan.nextInt();

 Shape[] shape = new Shape[num];

    for(int i = 0;i < num;i++){
        System.out.print("Enter the choice (Square, Rectangle, or Circle): ");       
        int shapeType = scan.nextInt();

        if(shapeType == 1){
                System.out.print("Enter the color: ");
                String color = scan.next();
                System.out.print("Enter the side length of the square: ");
                double sideLength = scan.nextDouble();
                Square sq = new TestShapes(). new Square(color,sideLength);
                shape[i] = sq;
                shape[i].print();
        }
        else if(shapeType == 2){
                System.out.print("Enter the color: ");
                String color = scan.next();
                System.out.print("Enter the length of the rectange: ");
                double length = scan.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter the width of the rectange: ");
                int width = scan.nextInt();
                Rectangle rc = new TestShapes(). new Rectangle(color,length,width);
                shape[i] = rc;
                shape[i].print();
        }
        else if(shapeType == 3){
                System.out.print("Enter the color: ");
                String color = scan.next();
                System.out.print("Enter the radius of the circle: ");
            double radius = scan.nextDouble();
            Circle cr = new TestShapes(). new Circle(color,radius);
            shape[i] = cr;
            shape[i].print();
        }
    }

}

class Shape{
    String color;
    public Shape(){
        color = "red";
    }

    public Shape(String c){
        color = c;
    }

    public void setColor(String c){
        this.color = c;
    }

    public String getColor(){
        return this.color;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Color: " +color);
    }

    public double area() {
return 0;
 }
}

class Square extends Shape{

    double sideLength;

    public Square(){
        super("red");
        sideLength = 1;
    }

    public Square(String color,double sLength){
        super(color);
        sideLength = sLength;
    }

    public void setSideLength(double sl){
        this.sideLength = sl;
    }

    public double getSideLength(){
        return this.sideLength;
    }

    public void print(){
        super.print();
        System.out.println("Side Length: " + sideLength);
        System.out.println("Area: " + area());
    }

    public double area(){
        return sideLength * sideLength;
    }
}


class Circle extends Shape{

    double radius;

    public Circle(){
        super("red");
        radius = 1;
    }

    public Circle(String color,double radius){
        super(color);
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(double r){
        this.radius = r;
    }

    public double getRadius(){
        return this.radius;
    }

    public void print(){
        super.print();
        System.out.println("Radius of the circle: " + radius);
        System.out.println("Area of the circle: " + area());
    }

    public double area(){
        return 3.14 * radius * radius;
    }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape{

    double width;
    double length;

    public Rectangle(){
        super("red");
        length = 1;
        width = 1;
    }

    public Rectangle(String color,double length,double width){
        super(color);
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double w){
        this.width = w;
    }

    public double getWidth(){
        return this.width;
    }

    public void setLength(double l){
        this.length = l;
    }

    public double getLength(){
        return this.length;
    }

    public void print(){
        super.print();
        //System.out.println("Side of the rectangle: " + sideLength);
        System.out.println("Area of the rectangle: " + area());
    }

    public double area(){
        return length * width;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the print methods when all inputs are done. something like this:

```
...
//start input here
for(int i = 0;i < num;i++){
    System.out.print("Enter the choice (Square, Rectangle, or Circle): ");       
    int shapeType = scan.nextInt();

    if(shapeType == 1){
            System.out.print("Enter the color: ");
            String color = scan.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the side length of the square: ");
            double sideLength = scan.nextDouble();
            Square sq = new TestShapes(). new Square(color,sideLength);
            shape[i] = sq;
    }
    else if(shapeType == 2){
            System.out.print("Enter the color: ");
            String color = scan.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the length of the rectange: ");
            double length = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter the width of the rectange: ");
            int width = scan.nextInt();
            Rectangle rc = new TestShapes(). new Rectangle(color,length,width);
            shape[i] = rc;
    }
    else if(shapeType == 3){
            System.out.print("Enter the color: ");
            String color = scan.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the radius of the circle: ");
        double radius = scan.nextDouble();
        Circle cr = new TestShapes(). new Circle(color,radius);
        shape[i] = cr;
    }
}
//start printing here
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        shape[i].print();
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm a beginner with java and basically forgot I was just printing immediately

Comment: as @YeetariVsKekmet mentioned, consider using a switch statement so there are not that much big if else statements. That makes your code more readable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the input first and process it afterwards, just use two loops. The first reads the input and stores it in an array. After that, a second loop iterates over the array and does what is required.

```
int[] shapeType = new int[num];
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
     System.out.print("Enter the choice (Square, Rectangle, or Circle): ");       
     int shapeType[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
    int shapeType = scanType[j];
    if (shapeType == 1) {
        ...
```

This can be optimized, but requires just a few changes and additions to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `shape[i].print()` in the loop before all the choixes are made. You can try deleting those statements and display all the choice at once after your first for loop (by looping through your shape array)